# Loading pdb files for external assemblies in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

Scenario: I publish libraries to my personal nuget Server and pull these libraries down into other solutions using NuGet manager in Visual Studio. I've got some unusual behaviours in a controls library (stigzler.controls) which is consumed by another solution (call it MyFabApp) and I'm wanting to be able to place break points in it so when I run from MyFabApp, it stops at these points. It's very strange as `Debug.Writeline` in stigzler.controls doesn't function in MyFabApp despite working independently in the Solution it sits in.

Examining the build - there is no stigzler.control.pdb in the MyFabApp bin folder. Guessing that makes sense given it's pulled down from nuget.

I've disabled Just My Code in Tools>Options>debug. I also added the directory containing the stigzler.control.pdb file to (MyFabApp)`Solution>Properties>Debug Sources Files` - no dice. Also added the path to the pdb to Tools>Options>Debugging>Symbols - still no dice.

I'm obviously missing something - would appreciate advice. I'd like to avoid referencing stigzler.control on my local machine directly from MyFabApp, sticking with updates managed via my personal nuget server (assists with coding on the move).

Comment: Is your program built in release mode?

Comment: Good point. Yes, the assembly that I push to my nuget is. I assumed all nuget assemblies should be released mode. Struggling to think of a way around this. MyApp needs to get stigzler.contorls from nuget to enable portable working. How would I get around this?

Comment: With the debugger in break mode, use Debug > Windows > Modules.  Locate stigzler.controls in the list > right-click > Symbol Load Information.  Which shows where the debugger looked for the pdb file, ensure it is there.

Answer (score 1):

For release mode, there is embedded symbol option in DLL Properties -> Build-> General.
Open the library source file in the test application Visual Studio project and hit the breakpoint.

.NET

[image]

.NET Framework

[image]

Comment: Damn - so close! This looked like it, but I'm developing in Framework and can't see an equivalent.

Comment: @stigzler For framework, Properties-> Build -> Advanced -> Debugging information

Comment: Sorry - yes - your advice was good, Minxin. However, just compiling it as embedded didn't do the trick. I found a lot of other SO articles about this and the answer is quite convoluted. In the end, I gave up, realising I'm unlikely to develop the full app anywhere other than my local machine, so gave up on nuget + debug and went back to importing the local file. Thanks for your help though.